# How to find missing numbers in an integer array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I couldn't find a solution for this in Java. I need to write code that will take an integer n, and an array of integers that has numbers up to n(some may be missing), and the method will print out which numbers are missing

ex:  {2; 3; 5; 1; 2; 3} should print out 4, 6

Edit: Here is what I got from the comments suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong?

```
      public static void findMissingNum(int n, int[]a) { 
         boolean A[] = new boolean[n];
       for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
              A[a[i]] = true;
         }

      for(int j = 0; j < A.length; j++) { 

         if (A[j] = false) {System.out.print(A[j]);}


       }


    }
```

Comment: Are the elements in the array in order? Also are there empty elements in the array already there for the missing #s?

Comment: I think you should start reading some Java tutorials (if you know Java basics go to arrays)

Comment: No, for example
{2; 3; 5; 1; 2; 3} should print out 4, 6

Comment: @RSTAnce add that to the body.

Comment: I do know basics of arrays, its just this specific problem that stalls me and I cant find any reference or method thats even close to it

Comment: Nice! You've got it. Remember, if someone's answer helped you please accept or +1 the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this used as a homework or quiz problem before, the question is begging you to use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). Create an empty Boolean array of size `n` and for each number in the list set `array[num]` to `True`. Loop over the new array, and record all the instances of `False`, you know ahead of time how many there should be.

Answer (score 1):

The following ought to work:

```
public void find() { 
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] nums = {2, 3, 5, 1, 2, 3};
        int n = s.nextInt();
        boolean[] included = new boolean[n+1]; 

        for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) included[nums[i]] = true;
        for(int z = 0; z < included.length; z++) {
            if(included[z] == false) System.out.print(z+ ",");

        }
    }
```

This will print out all missing numbers including n (if it is missing). If n is not included then do `new boolean[n]`

The way it works is by first using Scanner to read in your int n. It has two arrays, an int array which has your numbers, and a boolean array which serves as a set of flags. The boolean array is initalized to the size of n. Then it loops through the nums array and sees what numbers are included in the array. If the number is included, its element in the boolean arary is flagged as true. Finally, it loops through the flags/boolean array, if the element at that flag is true, do nothing since its already there, otherwise if its false (meaning the # wasn't included) then print it.

Comment: I belive this is what @Bi Rico was saying but I don't know since I don't really know anything about hash tables.

Comment: OOH Now I understand, absolute life saver. Thank you.

Comment: @RSTAnce no problem! Glad I could help :D. If you want, a +1 or accept would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this solution in Java:

1. Create second array `A = [0,..,n]` of booleans. Initialize it with `false` values.
2. Iterate through input array: `for i = 0 to length(inputArray): A[inputArray[i]] := true`.
3. Check which indexes in array have value `false`, those are the values that You want to return.

Answer (score 0):

List< Integer > list = Arrays.asList(yourArray);

Then you can just create an array from 1 up to n with all numbers in order, and iterate through its elements checking for each one if your list contains it or not, adding it to another missingValues list if not.